# Java bytecode lookupswitch and tableswitch total instruction length

Tags: java, bytecode

With a given bytecode, when encountering a `switch` instruction, I want to know where the next instruction is (without running the code). In order to do that, I was thinking that I should calculate the total size of the instruction, including jump offsets or match-offset pairs. Is this possible? If it is not, how is it possible to know where the next instruction is?

Also, are there any other bytecode instructions with dynamic sizes (their sizes based on a variable)?

#### tableswitch

```
tableswitch
<0-3 byte pad>
defaultbyte1
defaultbyte2
defaultbyte3
defaultbyte4
lowbyte1
lowbyte2
lowbyte3
lowbyte4
highbyte1
highbyte2
highbyte3
highbyte4
jump offsets...
```

#### lookupswitch

```
lookupswitch
<0-3 byte pad>
defaultbyte1
defaultbyte2
defaultbyte3
defaultbyte4
npairs1
npairs2
npairs3
npairs4
match-offset pairs...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to read the values of `high` and `low` (for `tableswitch`) and the value of `npairs` (for `loopkupswitch`).

Also, `defaultbyte1` always begins at an address that is a multiple of four bytes from the start of the current method. A padding between `0` and `3` bytes is needed immediately after the opcode.

The length of `tableswitch` is equal to 1 for the opcode + up to 3 bytes for padding + 4 bytes for the default jump offset + 4 bytes for `high` + 4 bytes for `low` + 4 bytes for each jump offset (there are `high-low+1` of them). In total:

```
 1 + p + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4*(high-low+1)
```

where `p` is the padding between `0` and `3`.

The length of `lookupswitch` is equal to 1 byte for the opcode + up to 3 bytes for padding + 4 bytes for the default jump offset + 4 bytes for the number of pairs (`npairs`) + 8 bytes for each pair of `match` and jump offset. In total:

```
 1 + p + 4 + 4 + 8*(npairs)
```

where `p` is the padding between `0` and `3`.

There is another instruction [`wide`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.wide) where its length can be either 4 or 6 bytes. If the following opcode is `iinc`, then length is 6. Otherwise, it's 4.